# How to stop user loading page that contains RenderBody() directly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have an Umbraco site with the following structure:

```
Views/LayoutPageA.cshtml/
Views/ContentPageA.cshtml/
Views/ContentPageB.cshtml/
```

LayoutPageA contains:

```
<body>
    ...
    RenderBody()
    ...
</body>
```

and ContentPageA and ContentPageB both contain:

```
@{
    Layout = "LayoutPageA.cshtml";
}
```

Obviously, if I navigate to `/LayoutPageA/ContentPageA/` or `/LayoutPageA/ContentPageB/` the page loads fine but `/LayoutPage/` will crash because:

> The file "~/Views/LayoutPageA.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderBody" method.

How should I prevent the user from navigating to `/LayoutPage/` through the URL?

Answer (score 1):

dont use `Views/LayoutPageA.cshtml/`

you should use
`<a href="/controllerName/actionName">`  or   `<%= Html.ActionLink("menu1", "actionName", "controllerName") %>`

Answer (score 0):

The only way this would occur with MVC is if you had an action named `LayoutPageA` or you explicitly returned `LayoutPageA.cshtml` as the view, e.g.:

```
return View("LayoutPageA");
```

So, just don't do that. Ensure that your action names do not match a layout name, such that it would by convention be the view that would be loaded for the action. A good standard to prevent this from occurring by accident is to prefix your layouts/partials with an underscore, i.e. `_LayoutPageA.cshtml`. Since action names cannot begin with an underscore, the layout/partial will never be matched by convention.